# What is "dreadlock"? (note the "R")

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

Heard many times of **deadlocks**, but what is a **dreadlock** in the context of multithreaded programming?

**Update:** [IAbstract's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292527/what-is-dreadlock-note-the-r/6292563#6292563) links to a whitepaper which explains the algorithm named *dreadlock* (not a product it seems). It covers the concept quite thoroughly. However, to briefly summarize what it's about:

A common way of detecting deadlocks is to keep track of which threads are locking which resources. This basically produces a thread-to-resource graph, and when a cycle appears in this graph a deadlock has occurred. This method is known as a spin-lock and is also known for being expensive, so more efficient alternatives like simple locking-timeouts is also commonly used. The Dreadlock algorithm seems to be a solution for the inneffectiveness in regular spin-lock algorithms, by minimizing the amount of data needed to keep track of locking cycles.

Comment: Maybe this (found via Google): http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~ejk39/papers/dreadlocks-spaa08.pdf

Comment: @Felix: Cheers, might be a good candidate for an answer *hint* :-)

Comment: I think it's the fear of having deadlocks…

Comment: Cleared the close votes.  People really need to read more carefully, but it might also help if you explained a little more in what context you heard the term.

Comment: Whoever came up with that software name should never be asked to come up with another software name... never, EVER!

Comment: @Bill: Yes a context would be nice, but I just heard two guys at the coffee-machine trying to guess what the term means. Nothing worth mentioning really.

Comment: Ah, agreed.  That's nothing really to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dreadlock looks like a new product](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~ejk39/papers/dreadlocks-spaa08.pdf) or toolset you can use to find or detect deadlocks (although, by the time one occurs, you will be cursing the dreaded deadlock). (link supplied by Felix Kling)

Answer (score 0):

when a process is requesting for a resource and that resource is held by some other waiting process and the process is never able to change it's state, the situation is called as deadlock.